# Kotlin extract time form the date

Tags: android, kotlin, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I have a date with that format: 2027-02-14T14:20:00.000

I would like to take hours and minutes from it like in that case: 14:20

I was trying to do something like this:

```
val firstDate = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US).parse("2027-02-14T14:20:00.000")
val firstTime = SimpleDateFormat("H:mm").format(firstDate)
```

but I got crash  `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date`

How to take hours and minutes from that string ?

Comment: Where's the `'T'` in your pattern and where are the fractions of seconds? They are all in the `String` you are trying to parse... By the way, do you have to use such an old/outdated API? Why not `java.time` or `kotlinx.datetime`?

Comment: in addition to what deHaar has said about your pattern not matching, i'm not entirely sure if you even need to do parsing here, you might just get away with some string manipulation by the looks of it, what you want always sits after `T` and before the second `:`

Comment: how to handle T in my pattern ?

Comment: Add the `T` wrapped in single-quotes might work (but I'm not sure about it when it comes to a `SimpleDateFormat`. `java.time` has built-in formatters that automatically handle `String`s formatted as your example (ISO format).

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### One of the RECOMMENDED WAYs

In case you can use `java.time`, here's a commented example:

```kotlin
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

fun main() {
    // example String
    val input = "2027-02-14T14:20:00.000"
    // directly parse it to a LocalDateTime
    val localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(input)
    // print the (intermediate!) result
    println(localDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME))
    // then extract the date part
    val localDate = localDateTime.toLocalDate()
    // print that
    println(localDate)
}
```

This outputs 2 values, the intermediate `LocalDateTime` parsed and the extracted `LocalDate` (the latter simply invoking its `toString()` method implicitly):

```
2027-02-14T14:20:00
2027-02-14
```

---

### NOT RECOMMENDED but still possible:

Still use the outdated API (might be necessary when it comes to large amounts of legacy code, which I doubt you will find written in Kotlin):

```kotlin
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

fun main() {
    val firstDate = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
                               .parse("2027-02-14T14:20:00.000")
    val firstTime = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(firstDate)
    println(firstTime)
}
```

Output:

```
2027-02-14
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
val date = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy",Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
```